# Return result aSync function in method

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

First of all, I completely read all the answers on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) question, but despite that I come to realize that after years of scripting I ended up in the aSync hell.

I have a method that uses an async function. Depending on the result of that function, the method should return true or false.

So, simply said:

```
example = {
    overview: undefined,
    aSyncFunction: function (callback) {
        // Adds values to overview, which we will use in otherFunction
        callback();
        return this;
    },

otherFunction: function (data) {
    var result = false;

    this.aSyncFunction( function () {
        var available = this.overview[data.name];
        // result == filter overview with supplied data)
    }.bind(this));

    return result;
  }
};
```

I've created a JsFiddle to show you the exact situation I'm in: https://jsfiddle.net/copt436a/1/

Deleting the setTimeOut will deliver true, otherwise it is false.

Note, I'm cannot change *aSyncFunction* at the moment, so the solution must be somewhere in *otherFunction*

I tried to separate the callback function in a different function, but in that case the return value is stuck in that particular function *otherFunction* keeps returning undefined. Also using the return value of aSyncFunction does not give me the result I want, cause this returns *this*.

I'm completely stuck on this one, and probably the solution is quite simple.

Comment: You could return a Promise that will be fulfilled when `aSyncFunction` has fired, and set a `then()`,  or simply append the synchronous part following `otherFunction` in the `callback`

Comment: Forget to mention, no ES6.

Comment: Well the second part of my comment ("or simply ...") is ES5 and probably above compliant. It would become something like `otherFunction=function(data, callback){var result=false; this.asyncFunction(function(result){var available = this.overview[data.name]; callback(result)};` with `callback` being whatever you want to do with the result of the `asyncFunction` (`this.otherFunction(function(res){console.log(res)})`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/copt436a/2/